# jQuery selected options in conditional statements

Tags: jquery, html, forms, conditional-statements

I'm trying to display some text in a div named "msg_box" for each selected option. It works but not live. I have to refresh to see the result.

The js is..

```
$(function () {
    switch ($('#my_options :selected').val()) {
    case '1':
        $('.msg_box').html('You selected option one');
        break;
    case '2':
        $('.msg_box').html('You selected option two');
        break;
    }

});
```

the div where text should appear according to the selected option..

`<div class="msg_box"></div>`

and the form..

```
<select id="my_options">
    <option value="0">Select...</option>
    <option value="1">Something</option>
    <option value="2"> Something else </option>
</select>
```

Can someone please share how to change the html() dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use [a `.change()` event handler](http://api.jquery.com/change/) for the `<select>`:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/mjNC3/2/

```
$(function() {
    $('#my_options').change(function() {
        var str = 'You selected option ';
        switch (this.value) {
        case '1':
            str += 'one';
            break;
        case '2':
            str += 'two';
            break;
        }
        $('.msg_box').html(str);
    });
});
```

​

Comment: Mate, that's brilliant! Thanks also for sharing jsFiddle! I didn't know about it :)

Comment: @user - Glad it worked. Yeah, jsFiddle is very cool. Hang around here and you'll see it used a lot. :o)